# View added manually in code does not appear

Tags: ios

Once user double taps on image/screen, it adds an annotation on the screen. When it adds annotation image, I want also open a subview to add annotation detail. However, my subview does not come up.
Here is my code snippet.

```
  @synthesize iViewController;

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

    // adding gesture recognizer
      UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        [self.imvPhoto addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
        tapGesture.delegate = self;
    }

 - (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {

        // Here is the code for subview adding
        iViewController = [[InventoryViewController alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:iViewController.view];
        iViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 320, 460);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the InventoryViewController is made in the storyboard, then you show use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: to create it, not alloc init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @rdelmar feedback, here is the solution:

```
 iViewController = (InventoryViewController *)[self.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InventoryViewController"];
            iViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(728, 32, 300, 736);
            [self.view addSubview:iViewController.view];
```